# My program in getting stuck in a loop which it shouldn't do

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I have four nearly identical while-lopps in my program. The program is going through 3 of them but getting stuck in the fourth (the last).

What I am trying to achieve is a program that gives every player 13 random playing cards.

I have add the relevant piece of the program below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cards = new String[53];
    cards[1] = "1k"; cards[2] = "2k"; cards[3] = "3k"; cards[4] = "4k"; cards[5] = "5k"; cards[6] = "6k";
    cards[7] = "7k"; cards[8] = "8k"; cards[9] = "9k"; cards[10] = "10k"; cards[11] = "11k"; cards[12] = "12k";
    cards[13] = "13k"; 
    cards[14] = "1h"; cards[15] = "2h"; cards[16] = "3h"; cards[17] = "4h"; cards[18] = "5h"; cards[19] = "6h";
    cards[20] = "7h"; cards[21] = "8h"; cards[22] = "9h"; cards[23] = "10h"; cards[24] = "11h"; cards[25] = "12h";
    cards[26] = "13h";
    cards[27] = "1r"; cards[28] = "2r"; cards[29] = "3r"; cards[30] = "4r"; cards[31] = "5r"; cards[32] = "6r";
    cards[33] = "7r"; cards[34] = "8r"; cards[35] = "9r"; cards[36] = "10r"; cards[37] = "11r"; cards[38] = "12r";
    cards[39] = "13k";
    cards[40] = "1s"; cards[41] = "2s"; cards[42] = "3s"; cards[43] = "4s"; cards[44] = "5s"; cards[45] = "6s";
    cards[46] = "7s"; cards[47] = "8s"; cards[48] = "9s"; cards[49] = "10s"; cards[50] = "11s"; cards[51] = "12s";
    cards[52] = "13s";

    String[] player1 = new String[14];
    String[] player2 = new String[14];
    String[] player4 = new String[14];
    String[] player3 = new String[14];

    String used = "";
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    int i4 = 0;


    while (true) {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        int irand1 = rand1.nextInt(51) + 1 ;

        String card = cards[irand1];

        if (i1 == 14) 
            break;

        if (used.contains(card))
            continue;

        else {
            player1[i1] = card;
            used = used + " " + card;
            i1++;
        }
    }

        while (true) {
            Random rand2 = new Random();
            int irand2 = rand2.nextInt(51) + 1 ;

            String card2 = cards[irand2];

            if (i2 == 14) 
                break;

            if ( used.contains(card2))
                continue;

            else {
                player2[i2] = card2;
                used = used + " " + card2;
                i2++;
            }

        }


        while (true) {
            Random rand3 = new Random();
            int irand3 = rand3.nextInt(51) + 1;

            String card3 = cards[irand3];

            if (i3 == 14) 
                break;

            if (used.contains(card3))
                continue;

            else {
                player3[i3] = card3;
                used = used + " " + card3;
                i3++;
            }           
    }

        while (true) {
            Random rand4 = new Random();
            int irand4 = rand4.nextInt(51) + 1;

            String card4 = cards[irand4];

            if (i4 == 14) 
                break;

            if (used.contains(card4))
                continue;

            else {
                player4[i4] = card4;
                used = used + " " + card4;
                i4++;
            }           
    }

}

 }
```

To clarify, the while-loop the program is getting stuck in is:

```
while (true) {
            Random rand4 = new Random();
            int irand4 = rand4.nextInt(51) + 1;

            String card4 = cards[irand4];

            if (i4 == 14) 
                break;

            if (used.contains(card4))
                continue;

            else {
                player4[i4] = card4;
                used = used + " " + card4;
                i4++;
            }           
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: `while(True)` ---> in other words, please do this forever.

Comment: Also the last player has to have the "stars align" to find the remaining cards, it probably will finish but it needs to randomly select only the cards that are left, it could take a while. Might be better to just give the remaining cards to player four by finding the intersection of the two arrays.

Comment: You are trying to get 4 * 14 = 56 distinct cards from a deck of 52 cards, using a random number generator that only generates **51** distinct values. Even if you fixed the code to only get 4 * 13 = 52 cards, it still will never succeed, since you only choose from the first 51 cards. Change code to use `nextInt(52)` instead of `nextInt(51)`. --- And as [Elliott Frisch pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161242/5221149), `cards[39] = "13k"` is a duplicate value and should be `cards[39] = "13r"`

Comment: On top of several errors noted by others, you're creating a `new Random()` object with each iteration of your `while(true)` loop.  The correct way to use pseudo-random number generators is to create one static instance, then re-use it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

First, you could save yourself some time by initializing and declaring your `cards` (and you repeated "13k" with `cards[39] = "13k";` - so you don't have 52 unique cards). Second, I would use `Collections.shuffle(List)` to deal the cards. That could be done with something like,

```
String[] cards = {
        "1k", "2k", "3k", "4k", "5k", "6k", "7k", "8k", "9k", "10k", "11k", "12k", "13k",
        "1r", "2r", "3r", "4r", "5r", "6r", "7r", "8r", "9r", "10r", "11r", "12r", "13r",
        "1h", "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "10h", "11h", "12h", "13h",
        "1s", "2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "10s", "11s", "12s", "13s"
};
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cards));
Collections.shuffle(al);
String[] player1 = al.subList(0, 13).toArray(new String[13]);
String[] player2 = al.subList(13, 26).toArray(new String[13]);
String[] player3 = al.subList(26, 39).toArray(new String[13]);
String[] player4 = al.subList(39, al.size()).toArray(new String[13]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(player1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(player2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(player3));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(player4));
```

Comment: Better approach, but doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @Andreas `cards[39] = "13k";` does. OP doesn't have 52 unique cards.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Genius! :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See also [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161119/my-program-in-getting-stuck-in-a-loop-which-it-shouldnt-do#comment95152332_54161119).

Comment: Genies! Thanks for the alternativ code. But my code still didn't work even after I corrected the duplicate.